# Ubuntu One only downloads filenames

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I have installed Ubuntu One on two Android devices and two different laptops (running 10.x and now 11.1). After playing with it a bit, I have concluded that either:

1. I am missing something, or
2. I have unreasonable expectations (perhaps influenced by prior use of Dropbox).

Here is my experience in a nutshell:

- Photos taken by the Android devices upload to the cloud, no problem
- Those photos then download to the laptops, no problem
- Files marked for sync on the laptops upload to the cloud, no problem

But, **NONE** of those files download to the Android device until I try to open it.

Isn't the whole point that the files will magically appear on my mobile so they are all sync'd up and ready when I want them?

The only solution I have found so far if to physically touch each file to initiate the sync, which is far less convenient than just using an SD Card.

Answer (score 3):

If you try the Android Dropbox app, you'll notice the behaviour is the same. Imagine automatically downloading (syncing) all the gigabytes of data you have in U1 to your phone :) Usually, that's not what you'd expect on a mobile device. Partial sync will come at some point, though.